# Android application crashes,force close when user check GPS provider

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, provider

I created an application for shows location with Network provider or GPS provider user choice
via checkbox.When user choose not enable GPS work fine.But when user choose GPS enable the first time after debug in close area into home crashes...After repeat in open area work...and no problem work and inside home.
What happens?How i avoid this error?Needs change my code with different code application auto choose best provider?(Not user)This is my code....

```
  // Get the location manager
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
// default
if(gps_en==true){ //In previous activity with checkbox user choice preferences

    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {

        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");

      onLocationChanged(location);

    } else {
      latituteField.setText("Location not available");
      longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }
}
else{
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

// Initialize the location fields
if (location != null) {

    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");

  onLocationChanged(location);

} else {
  latituteField.setText("Location not available");
  longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
  }

}


java.lang.NullPointerException
loc.LocTracker.onSensorChanged(LocTracker.java:769)
android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:580)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)         
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you suggest me a better way for this point of my code?
Permissions are OK.I want app auto choice best provider GPS or Network
with accuracy criteria first.
Start with Network provider and if GPS provider has better accuracy if 
user is in an open area app use GPS provider.
Thanks.

Comment: You should post the LogCat snippet that shows the crash/exception.

Comment: I update it with LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the appropriate permissions to your manifest file?

I believe that you need one of the following for GPS/location code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Permisions is OK.I have both.My problem is best provider choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing this on the UI Thread you should probably do some research about doing this on the Background thread.  Doing this type of work on the UI thread is very time consuming for the app.